# Efficient Java language constructs to check if string is pangram?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, optimization, pangram

So far, i have came up with this. I have tried to minimize string operations and isolate solution to built in data types, arrays and integer operations.

I'm in search of much more elegant way to check for a pangram string, in java.

Elegant, as in minimum lines of code, other efficient algorithms are also welcome.

Please provide suggestions without lambda expressions.

```
    private static boolean isPangrams(String ip) {

        char[] characterArray = ip.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int map[] = new int[26];
        int sum = 0;

        for(char current : characterArray) {

            int asciiCode = (int) current;
            if (asciiCode >= 97 && asciiCode <= 122) {

                if (map[122 - asciiCode] == 0) {

                    sum += 1;
                    map[122 - asciiCode] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return sum == 26;
    }
```

Comment: Well, "improving" working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com ... anyway: it doesn't get much better, but you could be using a Bitset instead of an int array - why use numbers when true/false is what you really need?!

Comment: BitSet , was a neat input. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bitwise operations for that:

```
private static boolean isPangrams(String ip) {
    int flags = 0;
    for(char current : ip.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z') {
            flags |= 0x01<<(current-'a');
        }
    }
    return flags == 0x3ffffff;
}
```

[**jDoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/Vd)

The code works as follows: we consider an int which is a 32-bit number. Each bit up to 26 is a flag (a `boolean` so to speak). Initially all flags are `false` because we initialize `flags` with `0`.

Now we iterate over the characters of the string. In case the character is a lowercase letter, we set the flag of the corresponding flag to `true` (regardless whether it has been set to `true` before).

Finally we inspect whether the lowest 26 bits are all set to `true`. If so, `flags` is equal to `0x3ffffff` (which is a hexadecimal number equal to `1111111111111111111111` binary. If so we return `true`. Otherwise we return `false`.

Usually bitwise operations are faster than `if` statements and booleans so I expect this program to be a significant bit faster.

Comment: Why cast the `char` 'current' and store it in an `int` 'asciiCode'? All operations you do can be done with the original `char` 'current' instead of  'asciiCode'.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a hard to understand few lines answer:

```
private static boolean isPangrams(String ip) {
  return 26== (new HashSet(Arrays.asList(ip.toUpperCase().replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "").toCharArray()))).size();
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. make the string uppercase (to handle 'a' and 'A' as the same)
2. remove all characters not A, B ... Z
3. convert it to a `char[]`
4. convert the array to a `Collection`
5. add the collection to a `Set` to get rid of all doublettes
6. test the size of the set.

**You should realize that this code is not easy to read and not performant.**

Comment: Yes, it fails for performant part. However, meets my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can 'pack' a data if a string contains the given letter inside an int variable.

```
static boolean pangram (String s) {
    int check = 0;
    String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < lowerCase.length(); i++) {
      char ch = lowerCase.charAt(i);
      if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        check |= (1 << s.charAt(i) - 'a');
      }
    }
    return check == 67108863;
  }
```

The magic number in the end is `0b00000011111111111111111111111111`

Answer (score 0):

You could stop the whole method with an return false statement, if you find 
          map[122 - asciiCode] not equals zero, because since then its no pangram anymore and you spare the rest of the for() - am I right?
I know this is not the improvement what you expect (especially with only 26 steps) but just something that came in mind to me

```
        if (map[122 - asciiCode] == 0) {

            sum += 1;
            map[122 - asciiCode] = 1;
        } else return false;
```

Comment: I thought the definition of pangram was _all_ chars (a-z) _at least_ once.

Comment: You are right, a pangram must have every char at least once. 
I thought of a "perfect pangram" which contains every letter only once.

Wikipedia/Pangram: "A perfect pangram contains every letter of the alphabet only once and can be considered an anagram of the alphabet"

Answer (score 0):

The most effective solution O(n) time complexity:

1. Iterate through the string and put each letter into `HashMap` (`key: letter, value: count`)
2. Iterate through the map and check each letter from alphabet

Comment: The algorithm in the question is **O(n)** too. So no improvement in complexity possible.